# Ajax js call , Httpclient java impact on server

Tags: java, ajax, apache, servlets, apache-commons-httpclient

We have a server which will handle servlet call and fetch the data.
So we have two different type of clients

1. Java script client ,through ajax calls we make servlet call.
2. Http-Client java to make servlet call using NIO.

Note : Both are GET calls only.

Does these two different ways of calling servlet have any difference.
Will there be any difference of resources on server handling these different mediums....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they don't make any difference. Both clients are using HTTP to communicate with the server and as long as their requests are acceptable the server should/does not care what client is making the request.